# Can an endless/perpetual counter be built using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, math, counter

A client asks:

> ...Our company hauls sand and to date, we've hauled 1.7 billion
>   pounds and counting. I am looking to have a counter made; it needs to be
>   continuously counting and not revert back to the original number after
>   the page is refreshed. I need the counter to start at 1.7 billion
>   pounds and be adding 154 pounds per second.

Would there need to be a data source, or would such a calculation be tied to time? (eg: current server time)

I assuming there's probably a need to lock-in the current actual value, so the calculation would need to be adjusted weekly/monthly to reflect what's real. But it's really only SAND (not rocket science).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 3 things on your server:

- Initial value
- Initial date+time
- Speed

Then using those 3 you can calculate value at any moment.

If you want

> so the calculation would need to be adjusted weekly/monthly to reflect what's real.

you can make them customizable properties on some Admin UI. You even can let user enter new date and value and calculate speed using difference with the previous value. But still it makes sense to provide user some UI to override speed in case there would be some typo.

Now back to the main business. To make it more or less reliable I'd do calculation in two steps: first on the server side and then on the client side. First on the server-side you calculate current value as:

```
initial_value_for_client = initial_value + speed * (current_time - initial_time)
```

and put it into the page's JS together with `speed`. Then on the client side using simple `setInterval` you add `speed` to `initial_value_for_client` and update the HTML. By doing it in two steps you are not dependent on the client-side time zone. Your value is only wrong by the time it takes to download page and start its execution and that shouldn't be too much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes easy.

```
var startDate = new Date("2017-03-01T01:10:00");
var vStart =1700000000
var vPerSec = 151

setInterval(function(){
    var timeDiffSec = (new Date.getTime()-startDate.getTime())/1000
   var vCur = vStart +( timeDiffSec * vPerSec);
},1000);
   document.write(vCur);
```